# My Unity game works in the Testing tracks, but doesn't work in the production track

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

I have an build that works completely fine on Internal and alpha, so I finally uploaded to production, and now I get null reference exception errors. If i "Unpublish" the game from the Google Play Console, it will put the internal testing version of the app on my phone, and everything will work totally fine. They are both the same exact version. Theyre exactly the same build. Somehow me putting it on a production track is renaming my game objects.

I opened up android studio for the Logcat and this is what i get right when i open the app.

```
2019-06-09 22:48:03.263 24428-24453/? 
E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      at Playbutton.Start () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Here is the Playbutton's start function

```cs
private void Start()
    {
        coinsCollected = GameObject.Find("Coins Collected").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        birdsLasered = GameObject.Find("BirdsLasered").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
        highScore = GameObject.Find("HighScore").GetComponent<TMP_Text>();

        coinsCollected.text = "Coins Collected\n" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalCoins", 0);
        birdsLasered.text = "Birds Lasered\n" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TotalBirds", 0);
        highScore.text = "High Score: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();


    }



Does GameObject.Find not work in production tracks somehow? Im totally baffled.
```

Comment: can you share more info about this gameobjects that are you looking for and get null?

Answer (score 0):

I went into unity and just made another build with no changes and it works now. Well not really, i get a different error, but I will consider this question answered.